# How to use my custom API with Vue Metronic template Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, metronic

I've trouble when using Template Metronic Vue (demo 7).
I've difficult with using login/register default Metronic Template, so I want to make my custom Login/register and another method CRUD with Laravel MIX API, But when I requested API with Axios, the request always catch Error.

is there any special method when I access custom API in Metronic templates?

In this code, I want to try console.log(). This is code :

```
<b-form class="form" @submit.stop.prevent="onSubmit">

    <b-form-input
    class="form-control form-control-solid h-auto py-5 px-6"
    type="email"
    v-model="this.form.email"
    ></b-form-input>

    <b-form-input
    class="form-control form-control-solid h-auto py-5 px-6"
    type="password"
    v-model="this.form.password"
    ></b-form-input>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold px-9 py-4 my-3 font-size-3">
    Sign In
    </button>
</b-form>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'login',
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onLogin() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/getUser')
            .then(response => 
            console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.log('error created')
            console.log(error)
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1fKV.png)
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHpUM.png)

Answer (score 3):

To use this code you should remove two things:

1. Remove MockService initialization from the main.js

```js
// Remove this to disable mock API
MockService.init();
```

2. Remove API initialization from the main.js

```js
// API service init
ApiService.init();
```

Comment: Why this is not mentioned in Metronic docs! Thanks. https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/vue/docs/getting-started/api-setup

Comment: @EsrefAtak These instructions are from Metronic 7 with javascript code, docs you are referring to are Metronic 8 with typescript. If you want to use Axios separately from ApiService then you should remove ApiService initialization, the documentation assumes that requests will be handled through ApiService.